# Nextjs 13 with Redux Toolkit renders data twice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am using Nextjs 13.4 with app routing and redux-toolkit in my project. Using default **useState** my component renders properly. However when I switch to RTK **useAppDispatch** and **useAppSelector** it renders data twice when navigating to another page and returning to the homepage.

**Component:**

```js
export default function PropertyList({ limit }: PropertyListProps) {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  const properties = useAppSelector(state => state.properties.value)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPropertiesData = async () => {
      const propertiesData: Promise<Property[]> = getProperties(limit)
      const properties = await propertiesData
      dispatch(setProperties(properties))
    }
    getPropertiesData()
  }, [])

  const content = (
    <>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
        {properties &&
          properties.map((property: Property) => {
            return <PropertyCard property={property} key={property.id} />
          })}
      </div>
      <div className="text-center mt-4">
        <LoadMore limit={limit} />
      </div>
    </>
  )

  return content
}
```